# Weird Rotation With Box2D and CGAffineTransformMakeRotation

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics, box2d, box2d-iphone

I'm rotating a UIView using `CGAffineTransformMakeRotation` and rotation value is coming from a 2D Physics Engine called Box2D (you've probably heard of it). The integration seems to work fine except the rotation will rotate the UIView. Can't really explain it, so here's a video showing what's wrong:

http://screencast.com/t/uamth2O7mL

obj is a struct that has another struct called "frame" and a float called rotation. Both are 100% working fine.

```
UIView *view = [self.view .subviews objectAtIndex:i];

view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(obj->rotation);
[view setFrame:CGRectMake(obj->frame->x, obj->frame->y, obj->frame->width, obj->frame->height)];
```

Comment: When you work with rotations, set the **bounds** of the view (at least for the size), not the **frame**

Comment: @borrrden Perfect! Make it a Answer and I'll Make it the Answer. (By the way, you still have to set the Frame as well, to keep the physics working).

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the Comments (thanks again @borrrden) you also need to set the bounds of the UIView.

Per my code, here's what I added:

```
[view setBounds:CGRectMake(obj->frame->x, obj->frame->y, obj->frame->width, obj->frame->height)];
```

Comment: Lol I didn't think it would end just like that, but great!

Comment: Haha yeah, seemed way to easy of a solution. But, I guess it's just that easy sometimes!